# IIS 7 odd behaviour with windows authentication

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, active-directory

So I have set up a IIS 7 server with windows authentication, and all works well. I have an aspx (test page) returning the users name and groups.

Code:

```
        IIdentity WinId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
        WindowsIdentity wi = (WindowsIdentity)WinId;
        string userDomain = wi.Name.ToString();
```

the userdomain string returns (example) "DOMAIN/username"

however, I have only one user on my domain (same active directory groups as similar users) but he returns  "Server/administrator". I checked all the groups in security and he doesn't belong to them. So im out of ideas.

EDIT: See my answer below (figured it out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two places storing user accounts, local SAM store and Active Directory.

If you see "Server\username", it means you have logon to the machine using an account from local SAM store.

If you see "Domain\username", it means you have logon to the machine using an account from Active Directory

The confusion usually comes up when you have a local user account with the same user name as a domain user account.  The built-in account "administrator" is usually one of the most common accounts causing this confusion.

In order to make sure you logon using a domain account but not a local user account, you can specify fully qualified name at the logon time.  e.g. Domain\Administrator or Server\Administartor

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. He had a certificate attached to his user account that didn't get destroyed when using remote desktop connection. Thanks anyway.